# SQL Reserved Words when using sqoop export

Tags: sql-server, sqoop, reserved-words

One of my tables has a column named as a reserved word in SQL (Desc), and when running an export from Sqoop it fails with "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Desc'." when looking at logs.

Is there a fix to this other than changing the column's name?

Comment: Can you please share the command line you are using?

Also, did you try to use --columns argument to specify column names?

Comment: @Kobynet The command I'm using is: 
`sqoop export -D "sqoop.export.records.per.statement=10000" -Dmapred.task.timeout=1800000 
-Dfs.azure.selfthrottling.read.factor=1 -Dfs.azure.selfthrottling.write.factor=1  
--connect "connection_string" 
--table CtasCatalogo_02052016_001_001 
--export-dir blob_with_text_file 
--input-fields-terminated-by \0x7E --batch --null-string '//null' --null-non-string '//null' -m 1`
I'll try using --columns and see how it goes